# Run metro app from custom shell

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-shell, windows-embedded-8

I'd like to create a custom shell (WinForms) for Windows 8 Embedded Standard (Release Preview) which allows the user to run, install, or update applications (can be desktop and/or metro apps).

Therefore I replaced `explorer.exe` in the registry with the path to my custom shell, which works pretty well. When I attempt to run metro style apps using the [IApplicationActivationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see implementation detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx)), I get this error message:

> The app manager is required to activate applications, but is not
>   running. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80270257)

The event log doesn't contain any additional information (neither in `Application` nor in `TWinUI`).

Metro style apps run well when `explorer.exe` is used as a shell. I didn't find a process or service yet which I could simply start to allow execution of metro apps (I tried to run `WWAHost.exe`, but this fails with the error message `The system cannot execute the specified program.`). Starting `explorer.exe` manually doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, but with two years having passed by, there might be new options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have a solution for you, but seeing as this exception is unheard of (Google it, I dare you) I figured I would point out that I run into the exact same issue in the Visual Studio 2012 Designer trying to run it as a RemoteApp (installed on a Win8 VM in a VDI environment).

!The full exception as thrown by VS2012 reads[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9dqv.png)